# Setting claims in Ambient Data Framework prior to request a component presentation through oData

Tags: content-delivery, odata, ambient-data-framework, rel

Is it possible (and how), when requesting content through oData, to set claims before requesting content?

The idea here is to add for example a contact detail claim, like Client ID
and then from a REL tag, access ADF (Ambient Data Framework), check that value, and "modify" the output accordingly to that Client ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to brush up on your "read the documentation" skills. This functionality was added with Tridion 2011 SP1. Read all about it in this topic in Live Content "[Forwarding Claims to a WebService](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-60A85C75-7E64-4B08-AE84-06966E9BAE90)" (login required).

Short answer: yes, you can. How to do it is described in the documentation.